# Can't I send NULL as a parameter with a constructor?

Tags: c++

Lets say i have a Shape object that has a constructor like this:

```
Shape( width, height, radius, depth )
```

Now, I just have a silly rect so i dont need redius and depth... is it okey to do

```
Shape myRect(50, 50, NULL, NULL) ?
```

I know its not the best idea and I should use inheritance and stuff but this is the mess im in so can i use NULL like this?

Comment: As you also noted, this is not a good design. If you can, you should redesign your class hierarchy in the long term: make `Shape` an abstract class and derive classes `Rectangle`, `Circle` etc. from it, with their appropriate constructors. Of course, the common interface would be very thin, only functions like `draw` or `area`. So another alternative would be to use templates instead of inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what types radius and depth are. If they are integers, you have to use an out-of-bound value like -1 to indicate "not set" (out-of-bound could also be 0 if you declare it that way). If they are pointers, NULL could be used.

Actually what you describe is a common example of bad inheritance, and it's used in OOP teaching to show why not everything should be inherited. Shapes are just too different for this.

Comment: Its the mess im in. What about user defined objects as parameters? Will NULL still be the on to use?

Comment: I don't know if I understand your comment question correctly. If you use pointers you can set them to NULL as of the C++ language definition. If you use references, you are out of luck because there are no valid ways to make a reference null (you CAN do it, but only with dirty tricks and loss of all your C++ karma). Again, I would recommend to redesign as far as possible even if you are in a mess now.

Answer (score 3):

> can i use NULL like this?

No. `NULL` is a *pointer* value. In fact, the code will even compile (in C++) but it will just pass the value `0` to the `int` arguments, *not* a null-pointer, since the arguments obviously *aren’t* pointers.

The solution is to provide an overloaded constructor that takes only two arguments:

```
class Shape {
    // Your “normal” constructor
    Shape(int w, int h, int r, int d) {
        // …
    }

    // Overload taking only two arguments
    Shape(int w, int h) {
        // …
    }
};
```

And call it like this:

```
Shape myrect(50, 50); // Calls second constructor.
```

Of course, the design will still be bad as you’ve noticed yourself. One class does not fit them all.

Comment: Or assign a default value to the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> It's the mess I'm in

There is a counter-measure against this kind of mess which is called *Refactoring*.